# Chrome DevTools Command Line API, jQuery, dollar sign variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

*Sorry for the title because I don't know how to define the exact problem as of writing...*

The problem I am seeing just now is that, under some certain conditions, the dollar sign variable (`$`) from DevTools Console is not overridden after jQuery is loaded.

**Environment**:

- Open the DevTools Console on a page where `jQuery` is ***NOT*** loaded.
- Run the test cases in DevTools Console.
- Reload the page after each test case such that `jQuery` is unloaded.
- Chrome version: 37.0.2062.120 m

**Preparation code**:

```
function loadJqueryThenFire(func) {
    if (!window.jQuery) {  
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js';
        s.onload = function() {
            func();
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    } else {
        func();
    }
}
```

**Test case 1**<sub>*(anonymous function expression)*</sub>:

```
test = function() { console.log($); };
// this returns Console's "$" object
loadJqueryThenFire(test);
```

**Test case 2**<sub>*(named function expression)*</sub>:

```
test = function test() { console.log($); };
// this returns Console's "$" object
loadJqueryThenFire(test);
```

**Test case 3**<sub>*(anonymous function expression passed as parameter)*</sub>:

```
// this returns Console's "$" object
loadJqueryThenFire(function() { console.log($); });
```

**Test case 4**<sub>*(named function expression passed as parameter)*</sub>:

```
// this returns Console's "$" object
loadJqueryThenFire(function test() { console.log($); });
```

**Test case 5**<sub>*(function declaration)*</sub>:

```
function test() { console.log($); };
// this returns jQuery's "$" object (which is what I am expecting)
loadJqueryThenFire(test);
```

This behaviour also happens on the latest jQuery stable version (`2.1.1`).

My question is: could anyone explain why the `$` is not overridden? Would that be something related to how `jQuery` declare her `$`?

**Edit:**

Found some more peculiar behaviours...

**Test case 6**<sub>*(immediately-invoked function expression)*</sub>:

```
(function() {
    function test() { console.log($); };
    // this returns Console's "$" object
    loadJqueryThenFire(test);
})()
```

**Test case 7**<sub>*(nested function declaration)*</sub>:

```
function tc7() {
    function test() { console.log($); };
    // this returns jQuery's "$" object (which is what I am expecting)
    loadJqueryThenFire(test); 
}
tc7();
```

Comment: i think anonymous function and named function takes `$`'s value when the function is assigned to a variable where the normal function takes when the function is executed. (I am pretty sure that this is because difference in variable SCOPE in three types of functions.). jquery's `$` is logged when i log `console.log(window.$)`. *eager to see better answers*

Comment: I guess it's due to `V8`'s code optimization... Don't have Firefox on hands to test other Javascript engine right now.

Answer (score 0):

I did tests with Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 and in all cases DevTools Console $ is overridden by jQuery.

[image: Screenshot]